# How to redirect url after saving to model in backbone and express

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

I have a backbone model that takes in data from a form and then saves it as cookie values that I want to use later

```
   app.Form1Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'/save-outline/',
    defaults: {
        projectName : 'Untitled',
        Embargo: 'No',
        Angle:'1'
    }

});
```

on saving the model, and sending it to the url, 
running

```
res.render('dashboard/step2/index');
```

or redirect

produces a response but it is not rendering in the browser; I know that the data is coming back as an response;

What should i be doing in the model to redirect it to the next page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Levy pointed out, the correct format is:
`window.location = url;`

In 'SPA' frameworks, you usually don't do a lot of redirecting. SPA = Single Page Application (the Wikipedia page is fairly informative). If you would like additional reading:

- [Backbone Introduction](http://clock.co.uk/blog/an-introduction-to-backbonejs)
- [More in-depth demo of creating a SPA with Backbone](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698645/A-Beginners-Guide-for-Creating-Single-Page-Applica)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I knew that there was going to be some way of listening to the change in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone is a "SPA" framework so you usually don't do redirects but if that's really want you want, set `window.location` to the URL you want the browser to navigate to.

Comment: Thanks but what does SPA stand for ? i am pretty new to backbone, any thing i should read that can help me do this better ?